# How to load javascript using module

Tags: module

I am very new to Expression Engine .

I have created a module , i want to know how do i load/run it in the current template .

I want to add some custom javascript to the front end website , and i know that i have to use

$this->EE->cp->add_to_head('myscript');
or any other function

But i don't know where should i call this function . I tried to call it in the mod.my_module.php in construct function but nothing happened.

Is there something i am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [the answer I gave here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5697/how-to-load-javascript-file-in-my-module/5699#5699), and specifically this bit:

> If you want to output the JS file URL in your templates, create a
>   method in your mod file that outputs
>   `URL_THIRD_THEMES.'your_addon/js/file.js'` or something like that. Then
>   use `{exp:your_addon:your_method}` to output the URL in the template.

Using `$this->EE->cp->add_to_head()` only applies to Control Panel pages.

Comment: ok , thanks for the answer . i think now i am understanding how EE works .

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look a at my Theme Loader class, which does some extra things and makes code a little easier to manage for older versions of EE and various configurations.

https://github.com/objectivehtml/Theme-Loader